# Issue 500+ load to data in data tables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, datatable

We have using data tables j query in our site. (https://datatables.net/).
But 500 more data load in the page.(no error occur). then click any one page hyper link --> suddenly go-to lo-gin page.(session is destroyed).

But up-to 50 data we can load page is successful showed (session not destroyed). All are working fine.

Only problem for 400 or 500 more data load in data tables.

please help with me.

Comment: Why do you need to load them all in one go? It's slow simply due to the weight of data. I'd suggest you page through the results.

Comment: You can use pagination (https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html). For the SQL statement, you can do this by using LIMIT, OFFSET- FETCH NEXT

Comment: I assume you are using laravel. Use this package https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables , it'll handle the server side works.

Comment: If any change in my php.ini file

Answer (score -1):

If the data is more than 500 lines, sometimes datatables may "hang".

Instead of loading all the data, you could set the server side pagination and dynamically retreive the Db records. You would have pagination that uses AJAX calls between page changes, such as 1-50, 50-100.

This [documentation on server-side processing](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html) may help.

Comment: if any change php.ini file

Comment: 500 lines from database - it is very easy for server. In my opinion, the problem is when render so much lines on browser